# Remove autosuggest text when clicking off field

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, autosuggest

I have just finished adding a search bar into my page.  It pretty much all works fine, however, I would like the autosuggestions to disappear after clicking outside of the field. How would I do this? I am using HTML5 and my codes are:

```
$(document) .ready(function() {
    $('.autosuggest').keyup(function() {
        var search_term = $(this).val();
        $.post('search.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data) {
            $(".result").html(data);
            $('.result li').click(function() {
                var result_value = $(this).text();
                $('.autosuggest').val(result_value);
                $('.result').html('');
            });     
        });     
    });
});


<input type="text" id="autosuggest" class="autosuggest" onBlur="removeSuggestion();"> <input type="submit" value="search">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul class="result"></ul>
    </div>
```

Not too sure my php is needed but just in case...

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false) {

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term']);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT town FROM `boroughs` WHERE town LIKE '$search_term%'");

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
        echo '<li>', $row['town'], '</li>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know of a 99% solution. A 100% solution is a little more involved.

Add an `onclick` to the body that will close the popup. But this means that whenever you click anywhere, even on the popup, it will close. This is why you should add an `onclick` on the popup element that will `cancelBubble()`:

```
function (event) {
    event.cancelBubble();
}
```

This will ensure the `onclick` event stops and never makes it to the `onclick` handler of the body.

This is the 99% solution. It's not perfect because when you have 2 popups open at once, clicking on one, you will expect the other to close, but it wont of course.

---

The 100% solution will involve a global tracker that tracks all the popups and closes the ones that weren't clicked. I haven't really found good justification yet to go this far.

Comment: Thanks but couldn't get that to work.  I decided to give Jquey autocomplete a go and seems to work perfectly.  Hooked it up to mysql database and all good.  Thanks anyway!